# IntelliJ debugger shows incorrect line number in call stack

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ IDEA to debug Java code.
The code line number is 225, but the call stack shows 293.

How to fix this?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by:
On the Maven panel on the right hand side -> click the icon "download source and/or documentation" -> download source;

Answer (score 4):

This problem usually happens when the latest build is out of sync with the source code.  This can happen if you had changed the source code without rebuilding before you started debugging.  In that case, the line numbers may have changed.

To fix this, try doing a full clean and rebuild before you debug.

Comment: Tried but no luck. I did mvn clean and mvn compile. The problem is the same.

Comment: Try doing a Maven clean followed by install.  Do this from inside IntelliJ.

Comment: I did IntelliJ -> Build -> Rebuild Project. It did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Try recompiling or rebuilding before running the code again!